# Debuild gpg sign failed no secret key

Tags: linux, gnupg, pgp, development, deb

I've exported my key (through seahorse GUI) to key.pgp and imported on another Pc through the seahorse GUI on Ubuntu. After that I can't use this key for signing my deb package when running debuild -S to build source for launchpad. 
Do you have any ideas what to do?

Comment: Probably a problem with the GUI. I've written a small script that manually does the required operations with GPG keys, so I won't have problems with these in the future. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working remotely through ssh:

`sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry`

Choose the `pinentry-curses` or `pinentry-tty` alternative.